# Is there a systemwide hotkey to highlight a single word in OS X?

Tags: macos, hotkeys

I've recently been wondering whether there is a systemwide hotkey for highlighting a single word in OS X. Having used Microsoft Windows before I got used to CTRL+W in Visual Studio and am now missing this functionality. Is there any way to make this work and if possible systemwide, e.g. on every NSTextField in any application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{
    "^w" = selectWord:;
}
```

It doesn't work in Xcode or some other applications though.

See http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html and http://lri.me/keybindings.html for more information.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! Can't upvote though as I don't have enough reputation.